# Is a TCP inbound gateway automatically closed by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I'm using Spring `tcp-inbound-gateway` to listen for `Socket` connections on the server side.

I wonder if a socket connection is automatically closed after the response is end back to the client? I could not find anything about this in the spring docu: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#ip-endpoint-reference

```
<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gateway"
    connection-factory="factory"
    request-channel="channel" />
```

Further question: how can I specify a timeout for which the socket connection should be kept alive? And close the socket if the response was not send back to the client within this time interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `single-use="true"` on the `ConnectionFactory` and it will close the socket after sending the reply.

Use `so-timeout` to set the timeout socket option and the socket will be closed after inactivity. Also see `reply-timeout` on the inbound gateway.

See the [configuration section of the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-endpoint-reference) for all attributes and their meaning.

Comment: Also see `reply-timeout` on the gateway.